# I am not able to 'set checked' in dynamically added check box in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have added a few checkboxes dynamically via jQuery in my ASPX page and I have tried to  checked some checkbox default based on condition. It throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I have tried below methods:

```
$('#chl3388').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

and

```
document.getElementById("chl3388").checked = true;
```

Comment: use `.prop()` not `.setAttribute`

Comment: var res = DealLocation.split(";");
for (index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
  var selectedvalue = res[index].valueOf();
  var selectedlocationid = 'chl' + selectedvalue ;
  $('#' + selectedlocationid+'').prop('checked', true);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setAttribute() is a native javascript function, on a jQuery element you have to use .attr() (in general), or here, for attributes like checked, you should use .prop()

```
$('#chl3388').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. now there is no error but check box is not selected

Comment: Provide some more code to let us see where the problem come from

Comment: hi thanks for your response, i have closed loop before the code reached, now its working